# Inverse of XOR-Operation

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, xor

I do the following:

```
public static byte Merge(this byte b1, byte b2) {
    return (byte)(b1 ^ b2);
}
```

so I can call:

```
byteVar = byteVar1.Merge(byteVar2);
```

Now, I am searching for the inversion of this. I should implement an Unmerge-Method for calling:

```
byteVar3 = byteVar.Unmerge(byteVar2);
```

byteVar3 should now be the same as byteVar1.

I have tried:

```
public static byte Unmerge(this byte b1, byte b2) {
    return (byte)(b1 & ~b2);
}
```

But it doesn't work correct.

Comment: If for some odd reason you don't want to do the self-inverse for XOR, [here are alternative equivalent options.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or#Equivalencies.2C_elimination.2C_and_introduction)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

XOR is a self-inverse - so you can just use:

```
byteVar3 = byteVar.Merge(byteVar2);
```

(I'm not sure that "merge" is a particularly good name here, mind you... you've just got an XOR operation. It's not even clear why you'd want a separate method for it.)

Comment: That's one of the reasons for the popularity of XOR.  It's fast.  It *was* used for drawing routines when computers were much slower.  It was easy to undo.

Comment: @DavidCrowell: I remember using that on the ZX Spectrum when I implemented Logo for it...